# RequestAnimationFrame to draw using arc(), looks bad, how to do it properly?

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to create the animation for the arc percentage, but what's being created is looking bad. you can see steps* in the arc.
*lack of anti-aliasing

I wonder how to do this properly ?

http://jsbin.com/AqaBAWA/1/

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Are you referring to that seeming lack of anti aliasing (jagged edges)?

Comment: @Luka thanks for looking! That's correct, it's called anti-aliasing, I couldn't remember! Yes, it's looking awful so I'm trying to figure out what to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the jagged lines here's a version without them: http://jsbin.com/idEjAmA/1

I just added a call to the clear function on the context before the draw call.

Comment: this is awesome! I'm wondering what's the logic behind it and why does it work if we add that line context.clearRect() ? Thank you!

Comment: @heldrida basically its because it keeps drawing on top of it self so all the anti aliasing is added to itself